# Get the list of questions who has  unchecked Radio buttons on a page JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have 10 questions on my page and each question has a **Radio button Group (Yes, No)**.
I am trying to get the list of questions who has **unchecked Radio buttons** on the page on the click event of **Continue** Button .

```
 $('#btnContinue').click(function () {
    var result = '';
        if ($(":radio:checked").size() < 10) {

                    $(":radio:!checked").each(function () {
                        result += "," + $(this).val();
                    });
                    alert(result);
                }
 });
```

doesn't give me the required result. Please advice.

Thanks in advance

BB

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$('input:radio').not(':checked');
```

May I suggest that you amend to the following:

```
var unchecked = $('input:radio').not(':checked').map(
                    function(){
                        return $(this).val();
                    }).get().join(', ');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5RNrR/).

Comment: David Thank you. This is not working either. For example if Yes is selected for Question 1. I shouldn't see Question 1 in the result. But ur code is returning Question 1 because the Radio button NO is not selected.

Comment: You said you wanted the values of each of the unchecked radio inputs. Do you *really* want the unanswered questions?

Comment: My bad. I need the unanswered Questions. Edited the question.